# Why, when I have cases for every enum constant in a switch statement, must I still provide a default?

Tags: java, enums

I'm trying to declare an enum in Java and use a variable of that type in a switch statement, where all possible cases for enum constants of that type are covered.

```
enum MyEnum {
    FOO, 
    BAR
}

private static void test(MyEnum e) {
    String msg;
    switch (e) {
        case FOO:
            msg = "foo";
            break;
        case BAR:
            msg = "bar";
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("Enum is: " + e + " msg is: " + msg); //compiler error
}
```

Why is the compiler not capable of detecting that this switch will always initialize `msg` (or throw a NullPointerException because `e` is `null`)?

Comment: It's possible to create new instances of an enum using some reflection witchery.

Comment: @immibis Even if it was possible, the compiler shouldn't necessarily bother about it.

Comment: Most compilers are capable of detecting this, yet the Java Language Specification does not allow them to abort compilation. Instead it only [recommends](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11) a warning about missing switch cases for enum values.

Comment: There's no way to enforce at compile time that all cases are covered separately using switch/case. If a value must be returned for all enum constants, you can for example make that value a field of the enum.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Imagine if `MyEnum` was a separate class. Then it would be possible to recompile the `MyEnum` class, and add new values, without recompiling `EnumSwitchTest` (so not getting any errors).

Then it would be possible for another class to call `test` with the new value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a solution that works with a switch-statement, but you can use the [Enum Mapper project](https://github.com/tmtron/enum-mapper) which provides an an annotation processor which will make sure at compile-time that all enum constants are handled. I guess this gives the same result that you are asking for.

Moreover it supports reverse lookup and paritial mappers.